# Sql server sqllogship.exe...full docs and/or source code?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Are the internals and all the logic of sqllogship documented?

Eg so i can manage it directly, *without the wizard*? Or replace it with my own tool? (For example, to rewrite it in powershell or C# -- the goal being to instrument it more fully and allow for different transports for the logs [other than a file share].)

I find this syntax (which is real, from a live SQL 2014 instance, but created by the log ship wiz) to be impossible to fully parse:

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\sqllogship.exe" -Backup DB46C321-3453-48FC-9B20-C1823E2B534A -server WIN-2OOC0JPLR5K

What does the guid point to?

(Would be awesome if this were open sourced... Or better yet, ported to powershell and offered to the community...)

Comment: 'What does the GUID point to?' I don't quite understand what part of this isn't explained in the documentation that Kapil linked to.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure of any other tool which you are referring to, but i prefer to use this sql logshipping app and yes its documented, refer to below article!

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283327.aspx

Not surprisingly, the sqllogship utility is specific to log shipping, which must be enabled and working in order to use the tool. The utility lets you perform copy, restore, and backup operations for an existing log shipping configuration.

Comment: I enhanced the OP. How to understand the guid?

Comment: The tool you mention looks to be the native sqllogship tool, not a different one.